# What protocols are authenticated by Active Directory?

Tags: authentication, protocols

Most of the new authentication solutions (IDaaS) are focused on HTTP (for example implementing SAML and OIDC). What protocols does Active Directory support, that are not normally supported by IDaaS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which generation of IDaaS you are referring to but in general Active Directory (and other IAM solutions) tend to have better support for on-prem authentication protocols than IDaaS, which is a cloud bridge, does.

I find your question intriguing because I have never tried to compare them previously (they are after all apples and oranges).

I have made a start with a few of the common authentication protocols:

- Kerberos = AD
- LDAP = AD and IDaaS
- NTLM= AD
- OIDC = IDaaS
- SAML = AD and IDaaS

I am sure others may wish to add to or update this list. If that is the case please comment and I will update the answer.